# How do I introduce a delay in my chatbot's response to user queries in Watson conversation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

So I am building a chatbot using Watson conversation that can have arguments with people on certain issues. Currently, the bot responds instantly to any user input. one of the essential factors in creating the illusion of talking to a human being is that a human would take a little but of time to respond to any query. And so I want to introduce a delay in the bots response. I have not deployed it on a platform yet; just using it on the APIs 'Try it out' pane. So i don't know if delay will be a feature of the platform or the program on bluemix

Comment: This will be done by whatever bot framework or server you have fulfilling and sending the requests. You'd use watson middleware for the NLP, and usually a bot framework for sending messages. The bot framework you choose should allow you to send messages with typing indicator (if the platform allows it) or create a delay between messages.

Answer (score 1):

Any delays has to be done at the application layer. Try it out won't simulate delays.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The real problem is that people like to chat in broken messages. for example "I Think... That your argument is invalid" What I would like to simulate is the ability to wait a while for the user to finish typing all their messages, and then collate the and respond to the entire collection as one.